# is it possible to run a big query stored procedure from tableau?

Tags: stored-procedures, google-cloud-platform, google-bigquery, tableau-api

I have a stored procedure in Google Bigquery, I have established a connection with Tableau. I am able to see all the tables under the dataset but unable to see the Stored procedures written in the same dataset.

I tried to find information from Tableau page, but couldn't find any.

Would anyone explain if they have done this before or is this possible?
Or should I just end up creating the same stored procedure in Tableau custom query?

Comment: Does Tableau allow you to run a `CALL xxx()` statement at all?

Comment: I am not sure if they do

Comment: @YunZhang - Big query has no CALL xxx() statement. You can call the procedure directly using Select xxx() ;

Comment: @Iñigo there is CALL :)  https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/scripting#call

Answer (score 0):

You can connect to a [custom SQL Query as a Datasource in Tableau](https://help.tableau.com/current/pro/desktop/en-gb/customsql.htm).

In this case, you must provide the raw SQL that will return you a table you can work later, including calls to stored procedures.

I don't reccomend coding that raw SQL Query from Tableau: use the Big Query web interface for it (you can see all stored procedures, datasets, and partitions from it), then create a custom SQL Query in tableu and paste the query on it.

To access the stored prodedure (UDF), you need to prepend the dataset name before it.

Example:

Suppose we've got a simple UDF like this one:

```sql
CREATE FUNCTION dataset.addFive(number int64) returns int64 as (number + 5);`
```

We can call the function directly in Standard SQL. No CALL needed (like in Oracle):

```sql
SELECT dataset.addFive(5) as udfCall ;
```

or

```sql
SELECT dataset.user_defined_function(column) as udfCall from dataset.Table ;
```

Also, with a view:

```sql
CREATE VIEW dataset.view_with_udf as
SELECT dataset.user_defined_function(column) as udfCall from dataset.Table ;
```

*Warning* This works *ONLY* with BigQuery with standard SQL (probably that's your case).

If your function was made with BigQuery legacy SQL (and your UDF source is in Cloud Storage), this will not work.

In this case:

- You'll need to [create the UDF in Big Query Standard SQL](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/user-defined-functions)
  (with the create function statement Create function..).
- Then you can access it from RAW SQL, either by calling it directly or creating a view.

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion, but writing a custom query would again be writing the query of the whole stored procedure in Tableau. I was trying to find if there was a way the stored procedure would just be able to be called by Tableau.

Comment: You can just 'select columnq, stored_procedure() from table' as a raw sql query. No need to recode again

Comment: I am sorry I am not understanding, lets say I have a SProc in BQ, Dataset.Add5ToNum(Num1). I could use CALL Dataset.Add5ToNum(10); and get 15 as result. How can I get to use this in Tableau ? I have connected with Dataset, it shows other tables but not this stored procedure.

Comment: Just put the call into a select: Select Dataset.Add5ToNum1(Num1) as num1_plusfive from Dataset.Tablename; or Select Dataset.Add5ToNum1(10) to get 15.